# In rings without unity can one raise an element to zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring without unity how can we define $a^0$ ?

Can we raise an element of this ring to zero?

I'm confused because in a multiplicative group when you raise an element to the power zero it yields the group's identity element. Without it I think $a^0$ becomes meaningless.

Comment: Agreed, the notation is meaningless

Comment: No, you need to have a certain structure, e.g. it would work for the path algebra of a quiver; we could define $c^0$ to be the empty path of source $s(c)$. But I agree with you it doesn't make sense unless you have a structure of unitary ring in some smaller subring containing $a$.